# How to open and close the detailtemplate programmatically?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have 3 columns, and therefore 3 cells in which I have a button.

At the click of the button I would like to open / close the detail template

Without having the + icon on the left

HTML:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="info" title="info">
     <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
         <button mat-button (click)="clickInfoCell()">
         </button>
      </ng-template>
 </kendo-grid-column>

<ng-template kendoGridDetailTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
         //DETAIL TEMPLATE BODY
</ng-template>
```

TS:

```
    public onCellClick(event: CellClickEvent){
        this.myEvent= event;
    }
    
    //toggleTemplate
    public clickInfoCell(){
        //Close previous template
        //Open detail template
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a built-in mechanism with dedicated directives for this purpose.

Template:

```
<kendo-grid
    [kendoGridBinding]="gridView"
    [kendoGridExpandDetailsBy]="expandDetailsBy"
    [(expandedDetailKeys)]="expandedDetailKeys"
></kendo-grid>
```

Component:

```
public expandedDetailKeys: any[] = [1];
public expandDetailsBy = (dataItem: any): any => {
    return dataItem.ProductID;
};
```

You can read about the mechanism [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/master-detail/expanded-state/).

You can see a working demo in StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skfr1d?file=app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'kendoGridExpandDetailsBy' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'.
1. If 'kendo-grid' is an Angular component and it has 'kendoGridExpandDetailsBy' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-grid' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: What version of Kendo are you using?

Comment: Did you check out the demo?

Comment: "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^3.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^3.4.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^3.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^2.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^3.14.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^3.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.7",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.54.1",

Comment: What about the 'kendo-angular-grid' package?